# I am unable to download anything using "pip" function

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install any module for python using command prompt or PowerShell, then there is a message that shows up, the message is:

```
 File "c:\users\opkp\app data\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\opkp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\OPKP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\opkp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\users\opkp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\users\opkp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions'
```

I know it has the names of my drivers and all. Due to this, I am not able to download any module for python.

Things that I have tried and that failed me:

1. I Googled it
2. YouTube videos were not tackling my problem, what they were telling me is just how to install pip (which I already have) and how to add the path (which I have already done)

Commands that gave this error:

`pip install flask`

`py -m`  ( I don't remember it fully but i wrote it correctly )

`pip3 install flask`

and i have also uninstalled and installed python
etc.

Here is my error message in the command prompt:
[image]

I also tried that `py -m` statement but that also gave the same result.

Comment: Have you tried just removing Python/pip and starting fresh? Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: yeha but the final results were the same

Comment: If after all the suggestions, there is still no improvement it may lead to think that there may be something fundamentally wrong with your setup or the way you use it. You may want to head over to [_Super User_](https://superuser.com) for some more general advice, since your issue does not seem to be related to _programming_ or _software development_ directly.

Comment: ok i'll that out too

Answer (score -2):

You can try to re-install pip or even completely re-install Python.